# Detect the closure of an application Android

Tags: android, detect

I making a module that is integrated into an application so I can't use OnDestroy function to kill my CountDownTimer.

I want to detect when an application is closing because I use a CountDownTimer to change the content of an activity added to the application with my module. When I exit my application my countDownTimer continuous to reload another activity..

In the application, my module is called with :

```
interstitial = new ModuleAdView(this);
```

Where "this" is the context of the application.

It's possible to detect this with ActivityManager for example ?

Thank !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can override onStop(), it will get a callback from the system as your application is leaving the screen.

```
@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    //stop your countdowntimer
}
```